# dash library error library is not registered

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash app using docker. On running I am getting this error for `dash_bootstrap_components` and `dash_ag_grid`. This error occurs randomly, no fix pattern or time so I can not pin point on specific code block. But on clicking the refresh button of browser the error goes off and app works normally.

I am using below version:

```
plotly = "^5.19.0"
dash = {extras = ["celery"], version = "^2.16.0"}
dash-bootstrap-components = "^1.5.0"
dash-bootstrap-templates = "^1.1.2"
dash-ag-grid = "^31.0.1"
```

**For dash_bootstrap_components**

```
web  | created_at=2024-03-05 20:11:57, level_name=ERROR, message=Exception on /_dash-component-suites/dash_bootstrap_components/_components/dash_bootstrap_components.v1_5_0m1709669432.min.js [GET], line_no=828, logger_name=web.flask_app, module_name=app, func_name=log_exception, exc_info=(<class 'dash.exceptions.DependencyException'>, DependencyException('Error loading dependency. "dash_bootstrap_components" is not a registered library.\nRegistered libraries are:\n[\'dash\', \'plotly\']'), <traceback object at 0x7f6e1d6bd140>)
web  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
web  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
web  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1005, in serve_component_suites
web  |     _validate.validate_js_path(self.registered_paths, package_name, path_in_pkg)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 365, in validate_js_path
web  |     raise exceptions.DependencyException(
web  | dash.exceptions.DependencyException: Error loading dependency. "dash_bootstrap_components" is not a registered library.
web  | Registered libraries are:
web  | ['dash', 'plotly']
web  | --- Logging error ---
web  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
web  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
web  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1005, in serve_component_suites
web  |     _validate.validate_js_path(self.registered_paths, package_name, path_in_pkg)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 365, in validate_js_path
web  |     raise exceptions.DependencyException(
web  | dash.exceptions.DependencyException: Error loading dependency. "dash_bootstrap_components" is not a registered library.
web  | Registered libraries are:
web  | ['dash', 'plotly']
web  | 
web  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web  | 
web  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 1160, in emit
web  |     msg = self.format(record)
web  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 999, in format
web  |     return fmt.format(record)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/work/utils/log/std_logger.py", line 46, in format
web  |     raise e
web  |   File "/proj/work/utils/log/std_logger.py", line 44, in format
web  |     json_string = json.dumps(log_message)
web  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
web  |     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
web  |     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
web  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
web  |     return _iterencode(o, 0)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
web  |     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
web  | TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable
web  | Call stack:
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1030, in _bootstrap
web  |     self._bootstrap_inner()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
web  |     self.run()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
web  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 92, in _worker
web  |     work_item.run()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
web  |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
proxy   | 172.21.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024:20:11:57 +0000] "GET /_dash-component-suites/dash_bootstrap_components/_components/dash_bootstrap_components.v1_5_0m1709669432.min.js HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0" "-"
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 282, in handle
web  |     keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 334, in handle_request
web  |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1488, in __call__
web  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1466, in wsgi_app
web  |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 807, in handle_exception
web  |     self.log_exception(exc_info)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 828, in log_exception
web  |     self.logger.error(
web  | Message: 'Exception on /_dash-component-suites/dash_bootstrap_components/_components/dash_bootstrap_components.v1_5_0m1709669432.min.js [GET]'
web  | Arguments: ()
proxy  | 172.21.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2024:20:11:57 +0000] "GET /assets/css/bootstrap/theme/light/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0" "-"
```

**In Browser(F12)**

```
GET
http://localhost/_dash-component-suites/dash_bootstrap_components/_components/dash_bootstrap_components.v1_5_0m1709669432.min.js
[HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 14ms]

Uncaught (in promise) 
error { target: script, isTrusted: true, srcElement: script, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 1216, … }
```

**For dash_ag_grid**

```
| --- Logging error ---
web  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
web  |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
web  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
web  |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
web  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
web  |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1005, in serve_component_suites
web  |     _validate.validate_js_path(self.registered_paths, package_name, path_in_pkg)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 365, in validate_js_path
web  |     raise exceptions.DependencyException(
web  | dash.exceptions.DependencyException: Error loading dependency. "dash_ag_grid" is not a registered library.
web  | Registered libraries are:
web  | ['dash', 'plotly', 'dash_bootstrap_components']
web  | 
web  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
web  | 
web  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 1160, in emit
web  |     msg = self.format(record)
web  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 999, in format
web  |     return fmt.format(record)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/proj/work/utils/log/std_logger.py", line 46, in format
web  |     raise e
web  |   File "/proj/work/utils/log/std_logger.py", line 44, in format
web  |     json_string = json.dumps(log_message)
web  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
web  |     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
web  |     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
web  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
web  |     return _iterencode(o, 0)
web  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
web  |     raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
web  | TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable
web  | Call stack:
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1030, in _bootstrap
web  |     self._bootstrap_inner()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
web  |     self.run()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/threading.py", line 1010, in run
web  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 92, in _worker
web  |     work_item.run()
web  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
web  |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 282, in handle
web  |     keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 334, in handle_request
web  |     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1488, in __call__
web  |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1466, in wsgi_app
web  |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 807, in handle_exception
web  |     self.log_exception(exc_info)
web  |   File "/proj/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 828, in log_exception
web  |     self.logger.error(
web  | Message: 'Exception on /_dash-component-suites/dash_ag_grid/dash_ag_grid.v31_0_1m1709565075.min.js [GET]'
```

Any suggestions how to avoid this error?